# Xcode Swift: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x102e8ac50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x102e8b8d0)

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, swift, nsdictionary

I am trying to display my JSON information in the debug area but I am having a problem in which I have not found a solution.

First of all, let me display the code I have so far:

**BBUpJSON.swift**

```
import Foundation

class BBUpJSON {

    func loadBbup(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {

        var urlString = "http://xxxdsgn.xxxhost.com/json/jnslst.json"

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let bbupUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)

        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(bbupUrl!){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                var error : NSError?

                var bbupData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSArray

                var jnslst = [JSONExtrct]()

                for jnsextrct in bbupData{
                    let jnsextrct = JSONExtrct(data: jnsextrct as! NSDictionary)
                    jnslst.append(jnsextrct)
                }

                let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        completion(jnslst)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

}
```

**JSONExtrct.swift**

```
import Foundation

class JSONExtrct {

    var titulo : String!
    var imageUrl : String!
    var imageData : NSData?
    var imageUrl2 : String!
    var imageData2 : NSData?
    var imageUrl3 : String!
    var imageData3 : NSData?
    var marca : String!
    var color : String!
    var tipo : String!
    var ref : Int!

    init(data : NSDictionary) {

        self.titulo = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "titulo")

        let image = data["image"] as! NSDictionary
        self.imageUrl = getStringFromJSON(image, key: "image")

        let image2 = data["image2"] as! NSDictionary
        self.imageUrl2 = getStringFromJSON(image, key: "image2")

        let image3 = data["image3"] as! NSDictionary
        self.imageUrl3 = getStringFromJSON(image, key: "image3")

        self.marca = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "marca")

        self.color = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "color")

        self.tipo = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "tipo")

        self.ref = data["ref"] as! Int

    }

    func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) ->String{

        //let info : AnyObject? = data[key]

        if let info = data[key] as? String {
            return info
        }

        return ""

    }

}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let json = BBUpJSON()
        json.loadBbup(nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

So, when I run the app with a breakpoint in `for jnsextrct in bbupData{` in the **BBUpJSON.swift** file, it shows in the left side of the debug area that I have **20 values**. Everytime I run `po bbupData` in the right output of the debug area it just partially shows me 3 of the values out of the 20 I have in my JSON file. When I add another breakpoint in `completion(jnslst)` located at the end of the same swift file and press **Continue program execution**, I get the following error: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10c3c2c50) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10c3c38d0)`. It then redirects the error to `let image = data["image"] as! NSDictionary` that is located in my **JSONExtrct.swift**.

This is the [link](http://wlodsgn.x10host.com/json/jnslst.json) to the json file that is trying to extract the information.

**-----UPDATE------**

Modified the values of the strings in **JSONExtrct.swift** to:

```
if let imageUrl = data["image"] as? String {
            self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        }

        if let imageUrl2 = data["image2"] as? String {
            self.imageUrl2 = imageUrl2
        }

        if let imageUrl3 = data["image3"] as? String {
            self.imageUrl3 = imageUrl3
        }
```

And added the same breakpoints to see the results in **BBUpJSON.swift**. From the breakpoint `for jnsextrct in bbupData{`, it still displays me the same 3 values out of the 20 I have (don't know if that should show that way) when I type `po bbupData` in the output area. When I **Continue program execution** to `completion(jnslst)`, it doesn't show me the previous error but it shows me the following output result when typing `po jnslst`:

```
(lldb) po jnslst
[BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct, BonBonUp.JSONExtrct]
```

When I continue and add one more breakpoint at the last bracket, it shows me the following error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and it redirects the error to `completion(jnslst)` showing `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)`

**UPDATE 2**

[Breakpoint Line 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bogZx.png)

[Breakpoint Line 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMj1Z.png)

It seems that it reads just one value through `jnsextrct` and returns it to `jnslst`. Then when I add the other breakpoint in the next screenshot it goes to the next value. When I type `po jnslst` in the second screenshot, it returns one `[BonBonUp.JSONExtrct]` instead of 20 of them like in the previous update.

**UPDATE 3**

Already added `CollectionView` to the `Main.StoryBoard` but I am getting the following errors when I try to upload JSON information (Not images yet) to each grid. Under **JnsGridController.swift**, in order to receive the information from my `JSON` files, I had to create a new method that would callback as `didLoadJns`. Here is the part of that code:

```
jns = [JsonExtrct]()
        let json = JnsJson()
        json.loadJns(didLoadJns)
    }

    func didLoadJns(jns: [JsonExtrct]){
        self.jns = jns
        collectionView.reloadData()
```

In `json.loadJns(didLoadJns)`, `didLoadJns` use to be `nil` before I added the `func` method but I am getting the following error: `Cannot invoke 'loadJns' with an argument list of type '(([JsonExtrct]) -> ())'`

Also in **JnsJson.swift**, since I added that callback function in **JnsGridController** its going to be receiving arrays from `JsonExtrct` instead of `AnyObject` so I changed the function method from `func loadJns(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {` to `func loadJns(completion: ((JsonExtrct) -> Void)!) {` and now I am getting a similar error as the one in **JnsGridController**: `Cannot invoke 'dispatch_async' with an argument list of type '(dispatch_queue_t!, () -> _)'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is clear, you are trying to convert a string to a dictionary. In the json which you posted the key "image", "image2" and "image3" are strings.

```
{
    "titulo": "Verox's 1002",
    "image": "http://wlodsgn.x10host.com/img/jeans/vrxjns1002/veroxjeans1002_front.jpg",
    "image2": "http://wlodsgn.x10host.com/img/jeans/vrxjns1002/veroxjeans1002_rightside.jpg",
    "image3": "http://wlodsgn.x10host.com/img/jeans/vrxjns1002/veroxjeans1002_front_b.jpg",
    "marca": "Verox",
    "color": "Azul",
    "tipo": "Jean",
    "ref": 1002
}
```

so the correct way the get those values is:

```
if let imageURL = data["image"] as? String {
    self.imageUrl = imageURL
}
```

Avoid to use the explicit unwrap if you are not sure of the type of the object that you are try to casting.

**UPDATE**

The new error is of the same nature of the previous one, you are implicitly unwrapping a nil value that in this case is the closure `completion`. Your definition of the closure is `completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!` say to the compiler:

> Don't worry when you will need to use this closure it will certainly has a non-nil value.

But instead you are passing a `nil` value here:

`json.loadBbup(nil)`

The implicit unwrapping is useful but you are using it in a wrong way. If you want that the completion closure can be `nil` you have to define it as optional in this way:

`completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)?`

and the call it in this way:

`completion?(jnslst)`

Regarding the fact that the array contains only 3 values instead 20 there be a lot of reasons. I suggest to put a breakpoint in this line `jnslst.append(jnsextrct)` and watch the value of `jnsextrct`.

As general advices:

- avoid to use the implicit unwrapping unless you're certain the variable as non-nil value.
- use let instead var when you don't need to modify a variable; in this way you are certain that value never changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added an update to the bottom of my question. I know you mentioned in the last sentence of your answer to avoid explicit unwrap since my recent error in the update might be that error. I have been reading that is an error from swift since it is not perfectly able to compile it. What is your suggestion to go pass this error?

Comment: Thanks again for helping! Had to add an extra `?` to the **completion`?`(jnslst)** line at the end since it was giving me an error if I didn't add a `?` or `!`. Regarding adding a breakpoint to `jnslst.append(jnsextrct)`, I am going to post in my question two screenshots of the values.

Comment: Yes, you need to use an question mark to call the closure since now it is optional (I updated the the answer). For the other problem try to change the name of this variable  `jnsextrct` inside the loop into `jnsextrct2` so it doesn't conflict with the other on the for-each declaration. It should not be a problem but without have the code "under eyes" is difficult to find the bug.

Comment: Would you mind if I sent you the project so you can get a quick glance and help me understand it?

Comment: Sure, If you know how can do it you could create a github project so is more easy to share modification to the project.

Comment: Ok, when I have it in github, i'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: A did not find any error. I think the problem is the command `po` which does not print the entire description of an object if it is too much long. To be sure that the two array have the same length use this expression `po bbupData.count == po jnslst` instead.

Comment: Ok, going to use it. I am currently building the collection view so I can start getting my information and image up. Ill let you know if I have any issues. Thanks!

Comment: Hi lucky, I added a new update to my question. Appreciate your help!